# Uploading images from Imgur API gives 400 bad request

Tags: c#, api, imgur

I've looked up the API for Imgur and it said that it accepts a binary file when uploading images, and I have my code as such:

```
 private async Task Upload()
        {
            var openfiledialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openfiledialog.Filter = "Image files (*.png) | *.png";
            if (openfiledialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (var stream = openfiledialog.OpenFile())
                {
                    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                    var httpclient = new HttpClient();
                    httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Client-ID", "MYCLIENTID");               
                    httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                    var status = await httpclient.PostAsync("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload", new ByteArrayContent(imageBytes));
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

But, it give me a 400 bad request, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

[Response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JRfg.png)

Comment: Does the response tell you why the server didn't like the request? Read the body and see.

Comment: It doesn't really say anything meaningful, I've updated my post and posted an image of the response body.

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139), it seems like you need a `FormUrlEncodedContent`, with a single key/value pair: `image` to the base64-encoded image data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by converting the image to base64 and using text/plain content type header.

```cs
 public async Task<string> UploadImage(string base64Image)
        {
            var httpclient = new HttpClient();
            httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Client-ID", "MYCLIENTID");
            httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            var response = await httpclient.PostAsync("https://api.imgur.com/3/Image", new StringContent(base64Image));
            var stringcontent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var ImgurResponseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImgurResponseModel>(stringcontent);
            return ImgurResponseModel.Data.Link;         
        }
```